GitHub Advanced Security for Azure DevOps - Dependency Scanning failing today (same code/pipeline was working before)
We've a number of pipelines (one using yaml and one with the classic jobs) that have suddenly started failing today. Anyone seeing a similar error?
##[error] An exception occurred during execution.
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
   at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowNoMatchException()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Microsoft.AdvSec.Detection.Services.VulnerabilityOutputService.GetComponentDetailsForDisplay(Alert alert) in D:\a\1\s\tasks\dependency-scanning\detection\src\Microsoft.AdvSec.Detection\Services\VulnerabilityOutputService.cs:line 96
   at Microsoft.AdvSec.Detection.Services.VulnerabilityOutputService.LogAdvSecComponentAlert(Uri baseAlertsUri, Int32 index, Alert alert, List`1 locations, String branch) in D:\a\1\s\tasks\dependency-scanning\detection\src\Microsoft.AdvSec.Detection\Services\VulnerabilityOutputService.cs:line 47
   at Microsoft.AdvSec.Detection.Services.VulnerabilityOutputService.LogAdvSecVulnerabilitiesAsync(IEnumerable`1 alerts, String branch, GovernanceJobStatus processingJobStatus) in D:\a\1\s\tasks\dependency-scanning\detection\src\Microsoft.AdvSec.Detection\Services\VulnerabilityOutputService.cs:line 34
   at Microsoft.AdvSec.Detection.AdvSecOrchestrator.GetAndLogAlertsFromAdvSec(ScanResult scanResult, String projectId, AdvSecSubmissionArguments parsedArgs, String authToken, String repositoryId, String branchMoniker, Int64 sarifId, GovernanceJobStatus jobStatus) in D:\a\1\s\tasks\dependency-scanning\detection\src\Microsoft.AdvSec.Detection\AdvSecOrchestrator.cs:line 220
   at Microsoft.AdvSec.Detection.AdvSecOrchestrator.ExecuteDependencyScanningAsync(String[] args) in D:\a\1\s\tasks\dependency-scanning\detection\src\Microsoft.AdvSec.Detection\AdvSecOrchestrator.cs:line 148
Execution finished, status: -1.
Process terminating.
##[error]An error occurred during execution. See the logs for more information.

re-running pipeline reverting code, checking other projects with the same job in the pipeline
subset of pipeline code that was working before and now failing:
 steps:
         # Advanced Security Initialize CodeQL v1
         # Initializes the CodeQL database in preparation for building.
         - task: AdvancedSecurity-Codeql-Init@1
           inputs:
             languages: 'javascript' 
             querysuite: 'security-and-quality'

<build>
          # Advanced Security Dependency Scanning v1
         # Scan for open source dependency vulnerabilities in your source code.
         - task: AdvancedSecurity-Dependency-Scanning@1
           displayName: Dependency Scanning

We also had issues on  languages: 'csharp' pipelines as well today
to get the pipeline running we had to remove the init job as well as the scanning job as with just the init job it was failing to publish artefacts correctly

This is a bug and has been fixed according to InvalidOperationException in AdvancedSecurity-Dependency-Scanning. Please check whether it works in your pipeline now.

Yes, the Dependancy Scanning is working again!
Would be great in future if issues like this where posted to the status page now GHAS on Azure DevOps is GA
https://status.dev.azure.com/_history
